# Matching partial string to complete strings from an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, matching

This is a small section of a question that I was asked once. I have a variable array of strings like

> str list []={abcd,xyzw,qwer,abcde}

And my input is:

> input list[]={ab,abc,q,z,x}
>
> Output should be[]={abcd,abcd,qwer,-,xyzw}

Each input string should be matched to the **same characters (from beginning) in the list**. It should give the first available string as the answer.

The working approached I could think of were:-

1. **Brute force**: Time complexity O((number of strings in list)*(average length of input strings)*(number of input strings))
2. **Hashing**: It too is taking the same time.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: At least if I understand your intent correctly, a trie should be nearly ideal.

Comment: Please define "better". What is your time/memory tradeoff? What is the reason brute force isn't good?

Comment: Well, I basically have to reduce the time complexity here. Space trade-off is acceptable. Brute force works fine, but it exceeds the intended time limit.

Answer (score 1):

if your list[] is fix (or does not change very much), a trie would do the trick. While inserting, you have to do a bit of logic to identify the "first match", so if "abcd" is the first, you should not insert "abcde" (or invalidate it, if "abcd" could be discarded, so you have to do a bit of accounting and bookkeeping).

details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: The List is variable. It is also being taken separately in a different section of the programme. I'll read about Trie and see if it can help.